# Trig 101: Calculate coords of point P such that it is distance n from line AB and distance m from line BC

Tags: trigonometry

I've been in software engineering nearly 25 years and my trigonometry and maths skills are very rusty.  We have a requirement to drill a hole in the corner of a sheet of material, where the corner isn't a right angle and the hole must be 30mm from the top edge and 50mm from the side edge.  This was fairly easy to solve when the line `AB` is vertical because I could make assumptions about similar triangles and solve in two lines of trig, but the calculation where both lines are not aligned with the axes is stumping me.  I've a feeling it's going to involve simultaneous equations.  I've searched but this site tends to the pure math side of things and I'm not sure the terminology to use.

I hope someone whose skills are up to date can take pity on me and bash this out in a minute or two :)

[image: Diagram of lines AB, BC and point P]

We know the coordinates of the points `A`, `B` and `C`, the distances `m` and `n` are constants (50 and 30), and we know point `P` must be `n` perpendicularly from `AB` and `m` perpendicularly from BC.

*Edit*: in the real world point A is actually the origin 0,0 because the coordinate space of each piece of material starts at its bottom left corner.  This would probably simplify the calculation, but for purity we could continue to assume A is an arbitrary 2d point.

How would we calculate point `P`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I hope someone whose skills are up to date can take pity on me and
> bash this out in a minute or two :)

*It takes 1-2 minutes to "bash out", 20 minutes to write out in Latex. Hope it is helpful :-).*

Given  $A=(0,0),{B=(x_b,y_b)},C=(x_c,y_c),$

$\vec{BA}=(-x_b,-y_b), \tag 1$
$\vec{BC}=(x_c-x_b,y_c-y_b), \tag 2 $

$|\vec{BA}|=\sqrt{x_b^2+y_b^2}=a,\tag 3$

$|\vec{BC}|=\sqrt{(x_c-x_b)^2+(y_c-y_b)^2}=c,\tag 4$

$\boxed{{\cos \angle B=\frac{\vec {BA}•\vec{BC}}{|\vec{BA}||\vec {BC}|}=\frac{(-x_b,-y_b)(x_c-x_b,y_c-y_b)}{ac}=\color{red}{k},\sin \angle B=\sqrt{1-k^2}}}\tag 5$

We can get $\angle B$ with inverse trig function now:
$\boxed{\angle \color{red}{B} =\arccos k} \tag {5a}$

From difference formula of sine function:

$\sin( \angle B - \theta)=\sin\angle B\cos\theta-\cos\angle B\sin\theta=\sqrt{1-k^2}\cos\angle \theta-k\sin\theta$

$BP=\frac{n}{ \sin \angle \theta}\\=\frac{m}{sin( \angle B -\angle \theta)} \tag {5b}$
$=\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-k^2}\cos\theta-k\sin \theta}\tag {5c}\\$

cross-product (5b) and (5c)

$n\sqrt{1-k^2}\cos\angle \theta-nk\sin\theta={m\sin \angle \theta}$

$n\sqrt{1-k^2}\cos\angle \theta={(m+nk)\sin \angle \theta},\\\cot \theta =\frac{m+nk}{n\sqrt{1-k^2}}\\\tan \theta =\frac{n\sqrt{1-k^2}}{m+nk}\tag 6$

Therefore

$\boxed{\color{red}{\theta}=\arctan \frac{n\sqrt{1-k^2}}{m+nk}} \tag {6a}$

\begin{align}\boxed{|BA'|=\frac{n}{\tan\theta},|BC'|=\frac{m}{\cot\theta}} \tag {6b}\end{align}

$\vec {BA’} =\frac{\vec {BA}}{|\vec{BA}|}|\vec{BA’}|=\frac{(-x_b,-y_b)}{a} \frac{n}{\tan\theta},A’=-(x_b,y_b)(\frac{1}{a} \frac{n}{\tan\theta} +1)$

Let $\vec {A’P}=(p,q)\perp \vec {BA’}, \vec {A’P}\cdot\vec{B’A}=0,|\vec{A’P}|=n$

$p^2+q^2=n^2,p\cdot x_b+q\cdot y_b=0 ,$

$q=-p\cdot\frac{x_b}{y_b}$

$p^2(1+ (  \frac{x_b}{y_b})^2)=n^2$

$p=\sqrt{  (1+ (  \frac{x_b}{y_b})^2)}n \tag 7$

$q=-\sqrt{  (1+ (  \frac{x_b}{y_b})^2)}n\cdot\frac{x_b}{y_b}
\tag 8$

$\vec{OP}=\vec {OA’}+\vec{A’P}\\= (p,q)+ -(x_b,y_b)(\frac{1}{a} \frac{n}{\tan\theta} +1)\tag 9$

Please note all values in (8) are known by now.

P’s coordinates are the same as $\vec {OP}$’s coordinates. DONE.

[image]

Comment: Wow good work @BStar, didn't even need any trig functions! I had `tan` coming out the wazoo.  It works perfectly when I translate it into PHP and run it in my context. 
 I'm in the process of rewriting it where `A` is not `0,0`, for the opposite edge of our product.  I must say the 5th line loses me with the notation, I think the apostrophe is called 'prime' in that notation, but I think I can struggle through with your excellent foundation.  Question: What should I rewrite the title of this post, and any better tags to use, since it doesn't involve trig, or just leave it for posterity?

Comment: Ah I see, `A'` and `C'` are midway points on the lines `AB` and `BC`. Duh.  Plugging this formula in for our opposite edge (a 'top right' corner where `C` is over to the left) seems to give a slightly off position, debugging it now.

Comment: Question about line 5 in your calculation, my problem is that the vector `C'P` is not parallel to `BA`.  You state that `BA' = (m / |BA|) * BA`, which seems to presume that the vector of length `m` is parallel to `BA`.  I'm suspecting this is why my point P is coming out "slightly off" as I mentioned before.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Thanks BStar.. I'm suffering from my rusty maths. Your step 6 makes a few leaps I can't follow, whereas I could follow the vector math in the previous worksheet.  I don't see that `theta` is known, since we don't know the length `|BA'|`.  Ending with a statement about  `tan(theta)` leaves me at a dead end.  Could you please show where this would result in known coordinates of `P`?  I'm unwilling to reorient the axes such that `AB` is vertical, as I presume we would then need to use vector rotation matrices to rotate `P` back into original world coordinates.

Comment: All is updated now. Let me know if any questions.

Comment: Here is the process: First  calculate cos B and use arccos to get B. Second calculate $\tan\theta$ to get $\theta$ with arctan by using |BP| is the same from two triangles. Knowing these, we can get vectors BA’ and B’P, thus  vectors OA and OP. We get $\theta$ to grt vector BA’ in this case, not the other way around.